# There is an optional error while downloading the image from the storage, I have converted the string to URL

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, storage

There is an error for optional while downloading the image from the firebase storage, I am converting the string to URL to download the image

here is the code where the error is occuring , if any more code is required do let me  know

```
let imageUrl = URL(string: post._postuserprofileImagUrl)
        ImageService.getImage(withURL: imageUrl) { image in
            self.profileImageView.image = image
        }
```

Comment: Try put "!" after post._postuserprofileImagUrl like post._postuserprofileImagUrl! to force unwrap it, or post._postuserprofileImagUrl ?? "". Check if this works?

Comment: no, it is pointing to ( withURL: imageUrl ) and giving message of "Value of optional type 'URL?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'URL'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to (safely) unwrap the URL instance

```
if let imageUrl = URL(string: post._postuserprofileImagUrl) {
        ImageService.getImage(withURL: imageUrl) { image in
            self.profileImageView.image = image
        }
}
```

Or even (if `postuserprofileImagUrl` is optional, too)

```
if let userprofileImagUrl =  post._postuserprofileImagUrl,
   let imageUrl = URL(string: userprofileImagUrl) {
        ImageService.getImage(withURL: imageUrl) { image in
            self.profileImageView.image = image
        }
}
```

Comment: i guess this has been covered enough here , isn't it ?

Comment: @Sh_Khan According to the comments It seems that the code doesn't crash, so it's actually not a duplicate

Comment: it's not giving any error of Optional but it's not downloading the images yet, let me check whats wrong